# Why doesnt tcolorbox recognize the 'title style' key?

Tags: errors, tcolorbox

```
\tcbset{colback=white,colframe=black,coltitle=black,colback=white}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,title=Quantum Lyapunov Control Theory,title style={white}]   %it will show errors

 .
 .
 .
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)),starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier.

Answer (score 6):

From `tcolorbox`'s documentation:

[image]

So you have to put `title engine=path` (or one of the others listed) to allow the `title style` key to be used. These options require the `skins` library to be loaded: `\tcbuselibrary{skins}`.

In the picture above, the key `enhanced` is used, which internally sets `title engine=path`.

Comment: Funnily enough, the very example shown in your pic did not pass `title engine`. I think the OP didn't load `skins` library, maybe? Edit: Oh, it's loaded by enhanced. I don't get the error that OP mentioned if `skins` is loaded and `title engine` is set to `standard`. Just that the style is not set.

Comment: @Troy Good point! Indeed, I went to the documentation and the `enhanced` option is an abbreviation for a set of options which, among others, contains `title engine=path`. And, as you said, it comes from the `skins` library. I'll update my answer :) Edit: Strange... I don't get the error either. Hard to guess without the MWE :/

Comment: The error appears if `skins` is not loaded, which I suspect to be the case. But, you're right. Who else would know except OP? :)